# Create Multi Column Text in PhpFox inside Blog/Events/Pages Text Editor

Tags: phpfox

PhpFox Tiny MCE Editor lets us write regular single column text.

How can i write three column text like in other CMS's.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

[The link to where I found this information](http://www.phpfoxcamp.com/topic/566-tinymce-adding-buttons-and-plugins/). This will allow you to create tables in your posts along with other added features.

1- Log into your Admin Panel

2- Go to Settings-->Manage Settings-->TinyMCE

3- In Advanced Button 1 : you have this;

```
bold,italic,underline,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,link,unlink,separator,fontselect,fontsizeselect,forecolor
```

Replace with this;

```
bold,italic,underline,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,link,unlink,separator,fontselect,fontsizeselect,forecolor,
justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,backcolor,code
```

4- In Advanced Button 2, add this;

```
ltr,rtl,tablecontrols
```

5- In Plugins, add this;

```
directionality,table
```